# Rolling Linear Regression | To turn weekly into annual

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm having difficulty transforming weekly data that rolls over every 52 weeks for annual regressions.

Here is what I'm trying to do but I get the error "Error interpreting categorical data: all items must be hashable FDX ~ SP50". I believe this is because I'm trying to use the pandas rolling function.

```
df = pd.read_excel("dataset\Special_Proj.xlsx") 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')

def rollingwindow():
    tickers = ['FDX', 'BRK.A', 'MSFT', 'NVDA', 'INTC', 'AMD', 'JPM', 'T', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GS']
    year = ['Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6', 'Year 7', 'Year 8', 'Year 9', 'Year 10',
    'Year 11', 'Year 12', 'Year 13','Year 14','Year 15','Year 16','Year 17','Year 18','Year 19','Year 20' ] 

    moving_window = df[(df['Date'] >= '2000-12-29')].rolling(52)

    for t in tickers:
        for y in year:
            model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data=moving_window).fit()
            print(model.summary(yname="Status", xname=['Intercept', f'{t} Beta'],  
            title=f'Regression {y}'))
            print()

rollingwindow()
```

Here is the df head output to show what the data frame looks like. It is weekly stock prices from 1999-2021.

```
        Date    SP50     FDX     BRK    MSFT    NVDA    INTC     AMD     JPM       T    AAPL    AMZN      GS    
0 1999-12-31  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00  100.00 NaN
1 2000-01-07   98.11  116.03  100.71   95.45   89.21   99.62  112.31   93.64   90.51   96.78   91.38   87.66 NaN
2 2000-01-14   99.72  113.74   93.05   96.15   93.61  125.21  139.52   95.09   86.03   97.69   84.40   90.91 NaN
3 2000-01-21   98.10  101.98   94.30   88.87   95.34  118.98  131.32   93.89   88.21  108.27   81.53   90.98 NaN
4 2000-01-28   92.58   94.20   93.23   84.15   79.63  114.20  121.81   98.71   80.51   98.84   81.03   92.37 NaN
```

Comment: It's not clear what kind of transformation you are trying to perform.  The `df.rolling()` method does not transform anything itself, it just returns a `Rolling` subclass and you have to apply your desired operation to that object ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)). Also, you cannot compare a date against a string like you are doing.  You'll have to convert that string into a `pd.Timestamp()` or `datetime.date()` object.

Comment: Please also [edit] your post and show us what the input `df` dataframe looks like, ideally using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added the df. head to show what the data looks like. Basically, I'm trying to group 52 weeks or 1 year of data for each stock and run a regression on it while iterating for each year until 2021. @AlexK

Comment: So then you are not trying to turn weekly data into annual data, you are just trying to run each regression on one year's worth of data at a time?  You can filter the dataframe inside a loop over the years, e.g., `for year in range(2001, 2021): df_for_one_year = df[df.Date.dt.year == year]`.

Comment: Yes, that I what I'm trying to do. Run a regression on each stock for each year. Could you show me an example of where I use your ```for year in range(2001, 2021)``` @AlexK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function with a revised nested loop over years and tickers:

```
df = pd.read_excel("dataset\Special_Proj.xlsx") 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')

def rolling_reg(df):
    tickers = ['FDX', 'BRK.A', 'MSFT', 'NVDA', 'INTC', 'AMD', 'JPM', 'T', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GS']

    for y in range(2001, 2022):  # 2001 through 2021
        df_for_one_year = df[df.Date.dt.year == y]
    
        for t in tickers:
            model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data=df_for_one_year).fit()
            print(model.summary(yname="Status", xname=['Intercept', f'{t} Beta'],  
            title=f'Regression {y}'))
            print()

rolling_reg(df)
```